# Laravel: How to change `to` field of receipt in mail?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I found in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail) how to change the name of the sender but not where to specify the `to` field. I also did not find anything in the `config/mail.php` file.

When I send something to user `Max Mustermann` like this:

```
$user = \App\User::where('name','=','Mustermann')
                   ->where('vorname','=','Max')->first();
\Mail::to($user)->send(new Mail());
```

the mail will be send to

```
Mustermann < test@email.net >
```

but I want to send it to

```
Max Mustermann < test@email.net >
```

Where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message){
$message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!'); 
});
```

From the docs 
[Laravel 5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage)